# Add common auth header to all camel restlet route

Tags: rest, header, apache-camel, authorization, restlet

I have a big set of routes

```
from("restlet://api1").to("dest1-rest-url");
from("restlet://api2").to("dest2-rest-url");
from("restlet://api3").to("dest3-rest-url");
..
from("restlet://api100").to("dest100-rest-url");
```

All the routes are spread across different files.

Now, all the destination rest url require a AUTH header to be set. It would be tedious to set at each and every place.

Is there a way, I can set/configure a header , that is appended before calling any rest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO a possible and elegant solution would be to play with Camel interceptors. 
Using wildcards on "interceptSendToEndpoint", you should be able to intercept **all** calls to "restlet*" (or "http*" endpoints) in order to insert/add an "Authorization" http header before continuing the route.
More info here:
http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

Comment: Though it dnt solve the problem. I give it to you. This wildcard method should help others

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ? I'm pretty sure it *should* work.

Comment: check  my answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer that solved part of my problem

```
interceptFrom("restlet*").process( e -> { e.getOut().setHeader("Authorization":"Basic <authkey>"); });
```

**Note :** You may have to set the other parameter such as Content Type, HTTP Method , Other header, body from Incoming exchange to out going exchange.